# Spring Data JPA to deep and weird mapping

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data-jpa, crud

Lately I'm trying to create CRUD with many-to-one and one-to-many. I'm having following weird results, and I can't deal with it.

Here's the JSON from /teams, what I've got

```
[
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "team1",
    "footballers": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "karol",
            "age": 0,
            "team": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "team1",
                "footballers": [
                    12,
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "name": "Pauluszka",
                        "age": 0,
                        "team": 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        13
    ]
}
]
```

and what I wanted to achieve is

```
[
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "team1",
    "footballers": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "karol",
            "age": 0
         },
         {
           "id": 13,
           "name": "Pauluszka",
           "age": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Here's my Pojo's

Footballer.java

```
...somecodehere
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="team_id")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class , property = "id")
private Team team;
...somecodehere
```

Team.java

```
...somecodehere
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
private List<Footballer> footballers;
...somecodehere
```

I would be grateful if you could provide me some tips, what should i change to achieve that i want.

Comment: And the question is ? You want to know how to generate some JSON? (in which case the question is nothing to do with JPA) or you want to know how to persist that Java model? (in which case no JSON relevance)

Comment: The question is what am doing wrong in my case that i'm achieving this weird json instead of the one i want to have.

Comment: Ok, so nothing to do with the JPA API then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`

Here you have example http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

You can use `@JsonView` annotation to specify which fields you want to serialize in selected view. This would allow you to ommit `team` property of `player` on demand.